# Jquery load() method not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, load

```
<input type="button" value="Load" id="load" />
```

`<div id="file"></div>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#load').click(function(){
   $('#file').load('test.html',function(){
    alert('File loaded');  
   });
  });
 });
```

it is working fine in Mozilla Firefox ... but in chrome it's giving an error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/Tanveer%20Hussain/Jquery/test.html. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access",in javscript Console...

Comment: Can you confirm what the path is for test.html? Is it in the Jquery folder as suggested in the error?

Comment: By default Chrome limits what you can load from the local hard drive.  This would work fine if both pages were on a web server.  And, I think there's a Chrome configuration option that will turn off this security check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is just that .load() for local files is blocked by Chrome for security reasons. If you are using it on a server it works, given that all of the files originate from the same place.

To enable a working version locally, try:

In Mac OS X, quite Chrome, enter in Terminal:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

In Windows, quite Chrome, enter in Command Prompt:

chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
(Maybe you actually have to have the path... I don't think so. If so, you'll have to find it yourself.)

In Linux, quite Chrome, enter something like this into the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are attempting to load local files and it will be blocked due to browser restriction for cross domain or local file access

Run that file from webserver. you can use simple python server

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

open in browser `http://localhost:8000/page.html` (example: page.html is page which loads 'test.html')

Otherwise, you can use chrome flags as suggested by `Ekansh Rastogi`